# #ifdef / #ifndef and #endif

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a piece of code that has to be run both on a CPU and CUDA-GPU and an other piece of code running on CPU alone. 
`#define ENABLE_CUDA` is what i 'turn on' to enable the CUDA code in the entire application.
Here is what my code looks like....

```
# define ENABEL_CUDA is the preprocessor directive to turn ON/OFF CUDA code.

CPU and GPU code --This piece of code has to be executed irrespective of whether CUDA is ON / OFF.

standalone CPU code alone -- This piece of code has to be executed only if CUDA is OFF.
```

My solution is :

```
#ifdef ENABLE_CUDA

  CPU AND GPU code
# else
  CPU AND GPU code
  standalone CPU code 
# endif
```

But this involves code duplication (CPU AND GPU code) in both the ifdef and else blocks, I would like to avoid it.

How can I accomplish it? What has to be done inorder to avoid duplication of code ? Any pointers regarding this appreciated...

Comment: Why can't you just put the `#ifdef` around "standalone CPU code"?

Answer (score 5):

```
#ifdef ENABLE_CUDA

  CPU AND GPU code
# else
  CPU AND GPU code
  standalone CPU code 
# endif
```

Is equivalent to:

```
  CPU AND GPU code
# ifndef ENABLE_CUDA
  standalone CPU code 
# endif
```

In general, if code is common to both `if` and `else` you can move it out of both.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use:

```
CPU AND GPU code

#ifndef ENABLE_CUDA
  standalone CPU code 
# endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside what the others have already said,

```
#ifndef ENABLE_CUDA
# define __device__
#endif
```

will take you a long way writing functions that run on the device if CUDA is present or on the host if not, without code duplication.